# Ant: How to compare timestamps?

Tags: ant, ant-contrib

In a long running Ant script, I have a target that gets called roughly once per second. (This is probably not a good thing, but let's accept it for the moment.)
I only want it to execute if its last actual execution was at least five minutes ago.

One idea for a solution is to maintain a `lastRunTimestamp` property, and compare the current time to that.

**Problem:** How can I compare timestamps in Ant?

Another solution that would also be welcome is a means of executing the target only at specified time intervals, so that the check would not be necessary.

I am using Ant 1.7.1 and ant-contrib.

Any ideas are greatly appreciated - thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Interesting question, and one which is a bit harder to answer than I originally thought.

You can use the `<tstamp>` task to set a time stamp that's five minutes old:

```
<tstamp>
  <format property="time_stamp"
      offset="-5"
      unit="minutes"
      pattern="MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss aa"/>
</tstamp>
```

Once you have that timestamp, you can use the *lastmodified* condition of the `<condition>` task to see if a particular file has been updated since. If you don't have a file, you can use the `<touch>` task to create one.

```
<condition property="has.been.modified">
     <islastmodified dateTime="${time_stamp}" mode="after">
        <file file="${touch.file}"/>
     </islastmodified>
</condition>
```

The only issue is that default properties are immutable. Once set, you can't change them. Fortunately you're using `ant-contrib` and `ant-contrib` allows you to change that via the variable task.

Comment: Cool, that should work! However, it requires a temp file. Maybe I could create timestamps using `<tstamp>` than can be compared lexicographically as Strings? This would reduce the problem to comparing Strings. No idea how, though.

Comment: Found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7412894/ant-strings-comparison which, combined with your answer, makes for a good solution.

Comment: Just discovered that `<islastmodified>` is an Ant 1.8 feature. In Ant 1.7, one must seek alternative solutions, such as writing the timestamp to a file.

Comment: I think the "format" _attribute_ in the example above should actually be "pattern" -- so `pattern="MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss aa"`